# How to select rows based on a column being true for one condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have following dataframe:

```
    Date        Type  Local 
0   2015-01-02   B     A12  
1   2015-01-02   B     A12
2   2015-01-02   B     B23      
3   2015-01-02   B     B23  
4   2015-01-02   B     C4
```

I want to keep only those rows which have 'local' value, that appears >100 times in the df.

I have tried:

```
df = df[(df["local"].isin(df["local"].value_counts() > 100) == True)]
```

```
df = df[(df["local"] == (df["local"].value_counts() > 100)]
```

```
df = df[(df["local"] == (df["local"].value_counts() > 100)) == True]
```

And none have worked. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `groupby().transform()`:

```
df[df.groupby('local')['local'].transform('size') > 100 ]
```

or use `index` to get the `local` in `value_counts()`:

```
counts = df["local"].value_counts() > 100
df[df['local'].isin(counts[counts].index )]
```

Comment: Worked! I just dont understand why your second answer works, yet: df = df[df["local"].isin((df["local"].value_counts() > 100).index)] , doesnt!

Comment: `df["local"].value_counts() > 100` still contains all the `local` values, just masked with `True` and `False`. You want to keep only `True` values, so `counts[counts]` in my code removes all the `False` values.

Comment: Got it! Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
df[df['Local'].map(df['Local'].value_counts()).gt(100)]
```

As an example, see:

```
res = df[df['Local'].map(df['Local'].value_counts()).gt(1)]
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
         Date Type Local
0  2015-01-02    B   A12
1  2015-01-02    B   A12
2  2015-01-02    B   B23
3  2015-01-02    B   B23
```

For the above example only those with frequency above 1 are kept.

Comment: Worked! Thank you